# Sails Js blueprint update without primary key

Tags: sails.js, blueprint, updatemodel

In sails Blueprint API, update action is defined as `PATCH /:model/:id`. Here 'id' is the primary key of the model. But I need to find a record not from the 'id' but from another column value and update another column value. How can I do this with sails blueprint API?

Answer (score 0):

The `PATCH /:model/:id` is a shadow route(blueprint routes) that allow you quickly have RESTful routes for your models in Sails and as such the signature of it can't be altered.

However, you can opt into writing custom routes and an accompanying custom action since you want to have a more custom way of handling requests to such routes.

You can define the route in `config/routes.js` and bind it to a custom action where you can now query with other criteria using the WQL(Waterline Query Language)

You can check here on how to write such actions in Sails(you should be writing actions2 style actions if you are in Sails v1 so the article show you how to do that)

https://blog.sailscasts.com/migrating-your-sails-actions-to-actions2/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't want to create a custom action. I needed to find a blueprint endpoint that works without the primary key.  If the structure cannot be altered there is no other option but to use the `PATCH /:model/:id` endpoint.

Comment: Perhaps this might help? https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-custom-blueprints